# Big Word 2007 document slow

Tags: microsoft-word, performance

I have a big Word document (about 150 pages).

It was very quick until about 120 pages. Then I added about 25 pages,  with the following content:
- 1 section with a small sized font table with smaller page margins than default
- 1 section with a lot of small tables (no Excel, just created within Word).
- Header & footer text

When going inside/beyond the first added section (and further) repaginating starts which is very slow and seems to start over all again after pressing a cursor key/page up/down etc.

What I tried:
- Moving the content to a new document. I don't like this because I need hours to fix the headers/footers.
- Copied it piece by piece, doesn't really change.

What I don't like:
- Turning off background repagination (only if this is the last solution)
- Removing normal.dot (I use 9 heading levels).

Comment: Sounds like the document has somehow become corrupted. What about if you copy the entire document into a blank document (using CTRL+A). Does the issue still occur then?

Comment: I tried again and it copies but it's still slow. HOwever the repagination problem is now gone. It takes about 15 seconds to move from one page to another from a certain section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Office 2010. Although it is still not fast, it is a lot faster in the 'problem' part of my document and most important: the repagination is quite fast.